# Open applications showing behind desktop icons when logging in after inactivity or after logout

Tags: 22.04

I'm currently experiencing some issues when I login, either after inactivity or after logging out.

In particular, the Desktop folders show in front of open applications, as in the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV3Go.png

Is there a way to revert this (e.g. to have the applications showing in front, and the Desktop folders behind them)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using exactly as shown in "Settings --> About" ? e.g. 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem therefore I created a Bug Report for Ubuntu please visit the Bug Report and press "I'm affected" so it gets more attention: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2009069

Comment: Hi Philip. Version is 22.04.2 (LTS). I started witnessing this unusual behaviour after installing a 3rd party software (Vivado from the company Xilinx), which is used to program FPGAs (it takes about 40G space on my /opt ).  If I have to guess, it could be related to the dependencies to run it on Linux. Did you experience it after installing a 3rd party software as well?